# Как при выборе из объекта, отобразить все значения массива

Tags: powershell

Доброго времени суток профи. Скажите, как мне, при выборе из объекта, отобразить все значения массива. Вот пример ниже, RemoteIpRanges в нем - это массив элементов. массив естественно отображается не полностью, а  мне надо как то отобразить полностью вместе с Identity, MaxInboundConnection и т.д.). Суть не конкретно в этой команде, а взять любую, где одно из полей будет массив.

```
Get-ReceiveConnector | select Identity, MaxInboundConnection, MaxInboundConnectionPerSource, Bindings, RemoteIpRanges
```

Comment: `$FormatEnumerationLimit = -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например:

```
Get-ReceiveConnector | select Identity, MaxInboundConnection, MaxInboundConnectionPerSource, Bindings, @{N='RemoteIpRanges';E={$_.RemoteIpRanges -join ', '}}
```

Comment: Гений. +100 Спасибо.